# I get logged out of session every time I go four levels deep in any directory with terminal

Tags: 22.04, xorg, directory, intel, mate

I'm a big fan of Ubuntu mate and I finally installed the latest LTS version (22.04) on my old 64-bit PC today. However, I found out that any time  I try to go four levels deep in a directory using the terminal (e.g. `cd dir-one/dir-two/dir-three/dir-four`), I get logged out of the session and I am asked to login again with my password.

I also experience the same problem when I choose *Open in Terminal* once I'm four levels deep in the file manager.

I'm confused as I would mostly use the terminal for navigating my files.

My `Xorg.0.log` content is below:

```
[   855.679] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   855.679] Current Operating System: Linux multiverse 6.5.0-14-generic #14~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Nov 20 18:15:30 UTC 2 x86_64
[   855.679] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-14-generic root=UUID=b96dec8d-4864-47d8-bb3e-e01eb7b3ae5a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   855.679] xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   855.679] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   855.679]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   855.679] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   855.679] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Jan 13 16:29:16 2024
[   855.680] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   855.680] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   855.680] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   855.680] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   855.680] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   855.680] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   855.680] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   855.680] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   855.680] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   855.680] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   855.681] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   855.681] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   855.681]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   855.681] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   855.681]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   855.681] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   855.681]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   855.681] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   855.681]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   855.681] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   855.681]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   855.681] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   855.681] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   855.681] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   855.681] (II) Loader magic: 0x55a5894bc020
[   855.681] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   855.681]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   855.681]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[   855.681]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[   855.681]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   855.682] (++) using VT number 7

[   855.682] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   855.684] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   855.684] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[   855.693] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:2a42:1179:ff66 rev 7, Mem @ 0xd0000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005110/8, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   855.693] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:1) 8086:2a43:1179:ff66 rev 7, Mem @ 0xd3500000/1048576
[   855.693] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   855.693] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   855.695] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.695]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   855.695]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   855.695] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
[   855.695] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   855.695] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[   855.695] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   855.695] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   855.695] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   855.696] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.696]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.21.1
[   855.696]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   855.696]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   855.696] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   855.696] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   855.696] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.696]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[   855.696]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   855.696]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   855.696] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   855.696] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   855.697] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.697]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[   855.697]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   855.697]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   855.697] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   855.697] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   855.697] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   855.704] (II) modeset(0): using drv /dev/dri/card0
[   855.704] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   855.704] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   855.704] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   855.704] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   855.704] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.704]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 0.0.2
[   855.704]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   855.705] (II) modeset(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   855.705] (==) modeset(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[   855.705] (==) modeset(0): RGB weight 888
[   855.705] (==) modeset(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   855.705] (II) Loading sub module "glamoregl"
[   855.705] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[   855.705] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[   855.710] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   855.710]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.0.1
[   855.710]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[   855.787] (II) modeset(0): glamor X acceleration enabled on Mesa Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset (CTG)
[   855.787] (II) modeset(0): glamor initialized
[   855.787] (==) modeset(0): VariableRefresh: disabled
[   855.787] (==) modeset(0): AsyncFlipSecondaries: disabled
[   855.787] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 has no monitor section
[   855.795] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 has no monitor section
[   855.902] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 has no monitor section
[   856.041] (II) modeset(0): Output SVIDEO-1 has no monitor section
[   856.042] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output LVDS-1
[   856.042] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer: SEC  Model: 4d45  Serial#: 0
[   856.042] (II) modeset(0): Year: 2007  Week: 0
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): EDID Version: 1.3
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Digital Display Input
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Max Image Size [cm]: horiz.: 33  vert.: 21
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Gamma: 2.20
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): No DPMS capabilities specified
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Supported color encodings: RGB 4:4:4 YCrCb 4:4:4 
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): First detailed timing is preferred mode
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): redX: 0.580 redY: 0.340   greenX: 0.310 greenY: 0.550
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): blueX: 0.155 blueY: 0.155   whiteX: 0.313 whiteY: 0.329
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Manufacturer's mask: 0
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Supported detailed timing:
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): clock: 69.3 MHz   Image Size:  331 x 207 mm
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): h_active: 1280  h_sync: 1296  h_sync_end 1344 h_blank_end 1416 h_border: 0
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): v_active: 800  v_sync: 801  v_sync_end 804 v_blanking: 816 v_border: 0
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): Unknown vendor-specific block f
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0):  SAMSUNG
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0):  LTN154X3-L01
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0): EDID (in hex):
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0):   00ffffffffffff004ca3454d00000000
[   856.043] (II) modeset(0):   00110103802115780a87f594574f8c27
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   27505400000001010101010101010101
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   010101010101121b0088502010301030
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   13004bcf100000190000000f00000000
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   00000000002387026404000000fe0053
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
[   856.044] (II) modeset(0):   004c544e31353458332d4c30310a001b
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Printing probed modes for output LVDS-1
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x60.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x60.0   71.08  1280 1328 1360 1440  800 803 809 823 +hsync -vsync (49.4 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x720"x60.0   64.00  1280 1328 1360 1440  720 723 728 741 +hsync -vsync (44.4 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   64.97  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.3 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x720"x60.0  116.95  960 1024 1128 1300  720 720 722 750 doublescan -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "928x696"x60.0  109.01  928 976 1088 1264  696 696 698 719 doublescan -hsync +vsync (86.2 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "896x672"x60.0  102.33  896 960 1060 1224  672 672 674 697 doublescan -hsync +vsync (83.6 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x576"x60.0   42.11  1024 1072 1104 1184  576 579 584 593 +hsync -vsync (35.6 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x600"x60.0   76.97  960 984 1000 1040  600 601 604 617 doublescan +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "960x540"x60.0   37.35  960 1008 1040 1120  540 543 548 556 +hsync -vsync (33.3 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   38.38  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (37.5 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "840x525"x60.0   59.59  840 864 880 920  525 526 529 540 doublescan +hsync -vsync (64.8 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "864x486"x60.0   30.71  864 912 944 1024  486 489 494 500 +hsync -vsync (30.0 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "700x525"x60.0   61.00  700 744 820 940  525 526 532 541 doublescan +hsync +vsync (64.9 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x450"x60.0   48.87  800 824 840 880  450 451 454 463 doublescan +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x512"x60.0   53.96  640 664 720 844  512 512 514 533 doublescan +hsync +vsync (63.9 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "700x450"x60.0   43.32  700 724 740 780  450 451 456 463 doublescan +hsync -vsync (55.5 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x60.0   25.19  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x405"x60.0   22.11  720 768 800 880  405 408 413 419 +hsync -vsync (25.1 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "684x384"x60.0   36.20  684 708 724 764  384 385 390 395 doublescan +hsync -vsync (47.4 kHz d)
[   856.045] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x360"x60.0   17.94  640 688 720 800  360 363 368 374 +hsync -vsync (22.4 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "512x384"x60.0   32.48  512 524 592 672  384 385 388 403 doublescan -hsync -vsync (48.3 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "512x288"x60.0   21.02  512 536 552 592  288 289 292 296 doublescan +hsync -vsync (35.5 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "480x270"x60.0   18.67  480 504 520 560  270 271 274 278 doublescan +hsync -vsync (33.3 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "400x300"x60.0   19.16  400 412 448 512  300 300 301 312 doublescan +hsync +vsync (37.4 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "432x243"x60.0   15.35  432 456 472 512  243 244 247 250 doublescan +hsync -vsync (30.0 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "320x240"x60.0   12.57  320 328 376 400  240 245 246 262 doublescan -hsync -vsync (31.4 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "360x202"x60.0   11.03  360 384 400 440  202 204 206 209 doublescan +hsync -vsync (25.1 kHz d)
[   856.046] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "320x180"x60.0    8.97  320 344 360 400  180 181 184 187 doublescan +hsync -vsync (22.4 kHz d)
[   856.055] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output VGA-1
[   856.172] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output DP-1
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): EDID for output SVIDEO-1
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 connected
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Output VGA-1 disconnected
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Output DP-1 disconnected
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Output SVIDEO-1 disconnected
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[   856.312] (II) modeset(0): Output LVDS-1 using initial mode 1280x800 +0+0
[   856.312] (==) modeset(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   856.312] (==) modeset(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   856.312] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[   856.312] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[   856.313] (II) Module "fb" already built-in
[   856.313] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[   856.313] (II) Unloading fbdev
[   856.313] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[   856.313] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[   856.313] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   856.313] (II) Unloading vesa
[   856.371] (==) modeset(0): Backing store enabled
[   856.371] (==) modeset(0): Silken mouse enabled
[   856.396] (II) modeset(0): Initializing kms color map for depth 24, 8 bpc.
[   856.396] (==) modeset(0): DPMS enabled
[   856.397] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   856.397] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: crocus
[   856.397] (II) modeset(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[   856.397] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   856.397] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   856.398] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   856.398] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   856.399] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   856.399] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   856.399] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   856.400] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   856.400] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   856.401] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   856.401] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   856.402] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   856.402] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   856.403] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   856.403] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   856.404] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   856.404] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   856.404] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   856.405] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   856.405] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   856.406] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   856.406] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   856.406] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   856.407] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   856.407] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[   856.407] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[   856.407] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   856.430] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized crocus
[   856.430] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[   856.430] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   856.430] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   856.431] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   856.431] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   856.432] (II) modeset(0): Damage tracking initialized
[   856.432] (II) modeset(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 211
[   856.520] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   856.521] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.521] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   856.521] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   856.524] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   856.524]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[   856.524]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   856.524]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   856.524] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   856.524] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   856.524] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   856.528] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.529] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   856.529] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   856.568] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   856.568] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   856.568] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.568] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.569] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.570] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   856.571] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event6)
[   856.571] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.571] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   856.571] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   856.571] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   856.573] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.573] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   856.573] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device removed
[   856.592] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event6"
[   856.592] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   856.592] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.592] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.594] (II) event6  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.594] (II) event6  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   856.595] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[   856.595] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.595] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   856.595] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   856.595] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[   856.597] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.597] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   856.597] (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
[   856.628] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[   856.628] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   856.628] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.628] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.629] (II) event0  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.630] (II) event0  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   856.631] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event1)
[   856.631] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   856.631] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   856.632] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Toshiba input device (/dev/input/event7)
[   856.632] (**) Toshiba input device: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.632] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Toshiba input device'
[   856.632] (**) Toshiba input device: always reports core events
[   856.632] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   856.633] (II) event7  - Toshiba input device: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.634] (II) event7  - Toshiba input device: device is a keyboard
[   856.634] (II) event7  - Toshiba input device: device removed
[   856.664] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/TOS1900:00/input/input8/event7"
[   856.664] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Toshiba input device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   856.664] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.664] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.665] (II) event7  - Toshiba input device: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.666] (II) event7  - Toshiba input device: device is a keyboard
[   856.668] (II) config/udev: Adding input device CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera (/dev/input/event10)
[   856.668] (**) CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.668] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera'
[   856.668] (**) CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: always reports core events
[   856.668] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event10"
[   856.670] (II) event10 - CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.671] (II) event10 - CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: device is a keyboard
[   856.671] (II) event10 - CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: device removed
[   856.704] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/input/input11/event10"
[   856.704] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   856.704] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.704] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.706] (II) event10 - CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.706] (II) event10 - CNF7051: Chicony USB 2.0 Camera: device is a keyboard
[   856.707] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Front Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[   856.707] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   856.707] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   856.708] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[   856.708] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   856.708] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   856.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[   856.710] (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.710] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard'
[   856.710] (**) DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: always reports core events
[   856.710] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   856.712] (II) event4  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.713] (II) event4  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   856.713] (II) event4  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device removed
[   856.728] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/0003:413C:2107.0001/input/input6/event4"
[   856.728] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[   856.728] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.728] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.731] (II) event4  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.731] (II) event4  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   856.732] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   856.733] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   856.733] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   856.733] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   856.733] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   856.734] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.734] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   856.736] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   856.756] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   856.756] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   856.756] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[   856.756] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   856.758] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   856.758] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   856.760] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event5)
[   856.760] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[   856.761] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[   856.761] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[   856.761] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[   856.762] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   856.765] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[   856.765] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device removed
[   856.804] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event5"
[   856.804] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 13)
[   856.806] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   856.806] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   856.806] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   856.806] (**) SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   856.808] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   856.810] (II) event5  - SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: device is a touchpad
[   856.811] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   856.811] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   856.811] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   858.892] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   858.892] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   858.892] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   859.155] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   859.155] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   859.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   859.428] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   859.429] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   859.429] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   859.698] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   859.698] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   859.698] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   871.544] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   871.544] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   871.544] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   871.803] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   871.803] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   871.803] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   872.073] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   872.073] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   872.074] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   872.344] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   872.344] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   872.344] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   875.887] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   875.887] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   875.887] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
[   876.155] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 19781
[   876.155] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   876.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   69.30  1280 1296 1344 1416  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (48.9 kHz eP)
```

Also here is the output of `inxi -SG`:

```
System:
  Host: multiverse Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Mobile 4 Series Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: Chicony Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: intel gpu: i915
    resolution: 1280x800~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Mobile Intel GM45 Express (CTG)
    v: 2.1 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: anything in [this Mate reference](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/random-logouts-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts/23851) which helps?

Comment: I'll recreate the behavior on my PC again and run the bash command in the reference to get my PC log to paste here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem was resolved by following the steps in [ricmarques' answer in Ubuntu Mate Community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/i-get-logout-of-session-everytime-i-go-four-times-deep-in-any-directory-with-terminal/27089/4). The required steps are below:

1. Create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`.
2. Put the following content in that file:

   ```
   Section "Device"
   Identifier "Intel Graphics"
   Driver "intel"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Then reboot the computer.